# Flawed Power Series Uniqueness Proof, and related question [Abbott's Understanding Analysis]

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, power-series

I've been working through some problems on power series in Abbott's understanding analysis, and I've been working on an exercise on the uniqueness of power series. However, in comparing my answer to the starts of others' proofs it seems that this would be incorrect. However, in this logic I can't seem to find a flaw (at least using real numbers)

The question starts from the following
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}x^{n}
\end{equation}
$$\forall x \in (-R,R)$$

My logic then starts as such: $ 0< x_{1} < R$ can then be chosen, such that each series converges uniformly. We can then rewrite this as the following new power series, which should also converge at $x_{1}:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_{n}x^{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n} - b_{n}x^{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n} -\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_{n}x^{n} = f(x) - f(x) = 0 
\end{equation}
where $a_{n} -b_{n} = c_{n} \forall n$.

Now, since this series converges at $x_{1}$, we should be able to define $x_{2} = (1/2) x_{1} > 0$. Then because $|x_{2}| < |x_{1}|$, the series should converge absolutely at $x_{2}$. As a result we can write the following:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|c_{n}x_{2}^{n}| = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|c_{n}||x_{2}|^{n} =0
\end{equation}
Now for this new series the sequence of partial sums will be increasing, and hence if any term in the sequence is non-zero, the series cannot converge to zero. As a result, we must conclude that
$$c_{n} = 0 \hspace{20pt} \forall n$$
(since $|x_{2}|^{n} > 0$)

This in turn implies that the coefficients are equal for all n.

I was wondering if you might be able to help answer find where I've jumped in my logic.

This is also in turn related to exercise 6.5.10 in Abbott:

Let $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}x^{n} $ converge on $(−R, R)$, and assume
$(x_{n}) \to 0$ with $x_{n} \neq 0$. If $g(x_{n}) = 0 \forall n \in N$, show that $g(x)$ must be
identically zero on all of $(−R, R)$.

In this I'd like to use the same logic, by taking an element of the sequence at which the sequence converges, and then finding another element of the sequence, which is smaller in absolute value, at the series which must in turn converge absolutely, and using this to prove that the coefficients are all zero in a similar manner to above.

Is this method of proof for this second exercise similarly flawed?

Thanks in advance for any help you can supply.

Comment: Hint: Set $f(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}c_n x^n$ for $|x|<R$ and assume $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in(-R,R)$. Notice that at $x=0$ $0=f(0)=c_0$, thus
$$f(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=1}c_nx^n=x\sum^\infty_{n=0}c_{n+1}x^n$$
As $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in(-R,R)$, $f_1(x)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}c_{n+1}x^n=0$ for all $x\in(-R,R)$. As before, one obtains that $c_{0+1}=c_1=0$. Continuing this way (an induction argument) shows that $c_n=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thank you for that. I was also wondering why the question-listed proof was itself flawed, could you give any reasons for that?

Comment: You can't conclude that $\sum|c_nx_2^n|=0$. For example, the sine series $\sum(-1)^nx^{2n+1}/(2n+1)!$ converges absolutely at $x=\pi$: $$\sum(-1)^n\frac{\pi^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=\sin(\pi)=0$$ but $$\sum\frac{\pi^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=\sinh(\pi)\neq0.$$

Comment: I don't know the textbook you are using and the material built up to where you are. with the help of some complex analysis it is rather easy to show that the segment about $g$ in your posting is indeed true. I guess the idea is to check that $c_0=0$ and then $g(x)=x^m\sum_{n\geq m}c_nx^n$ for some $m\geq1$ with $c_m\neq0$. Then $x^{-m}g(x)=\sum_{n\geq m}c_nx^n$  has a similar property as $g$ and so $c_m=0$, which is a contradiciton$.

Comment: @mr_e_man, that makes sense, thank you so much for pointing that out.